# Both local and remote video call display black screen but audio works fine in agora

Tags: java, android, android-studio, agora.io

I am trying out agora sdk sample on android using java. when I run the app on my phone and remote device the audio actually works well but the video shows black screen. How do I solve this issue.

I have tried what was stated on agora docs but non worked for me.

1. I have checked permissions they are working fine
2. My front camera is working fine
3. I enabled the video on my code.

My Code

```
public class VideoChatViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = VideoChatViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int PERMISSION_REQ_ID = 22;

private static final String[] REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

private RtcEngine mRtcEngine;
private boolean mCallEnd;
private boolean mMuted;

private FrameLayout mLocalContainer;
private RelativeLayout mRemoteContainer;
private SurfaceView mLocalView;
private SurfaceView mRemoteView;

private ImageView mCallBtn;
private ImageView mMuteBtn;
private ImageView mSwitchCameraBtn;

// Customized logger view
private LoggerRecyclerView mLogView;

    @Override
    public void onJoinChannelSuccess(String channel, final int uid, int elapsed) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLogView.logI("Join channel success, uid: " + (uid & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
            }
        });
    }

    
    @Override
    public void onFirstRemoteVideoDecoded(final int uid, int width, int height, int elapsed) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLogView.logI("First remote video decoded, uid: " + (uid & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
                setupRemoteVideo(uid);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserOffline(final int uid, int reason) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLogView.logI("User offline, uid: " + (uid & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
                onRemoteUserLeft();
            }
        });
    }
};

private void setupRemoteVideo(int uid) {
    int count = mRemoteContainer.getChildCount();
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View v = mRemoteContainer.getChildAt(i);
        if (v.getTag() instanceof Integer && ((int) v.getTag()) == uid) {
            view = v;
        }
    }

    if (view != null) {
        return;
    }

   
    mRemoteView = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
    mRemoteContainer.addView(mRemoteView);
    // Initializes the video view of a remote user.
    mRtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(new VideoCanvas(mRemoteView, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN, uid));
    mRemoteView.setTag(uid);
}

private void onRemoteUserLeft() {
    removeRemoteVideo();
}

private void removeRemoteVideo() {
    if (mRemoteView != null) {
        mRemoteContainer.removeView(mRemoteView);
    }
    // Destroys remote view
    mRemoteView = null;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_chat_view);
    initUI();

    // Ask for permissions at runtime.
    // This is just an example set of permissions. Other permissions
    // may be needed, and please refer to our online documents.
    if (checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[0], PERMISSION_REQ_ID) &&
            checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[1], PERMISSION_REQ_ID) &&
            checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[2], PERMISSION_REQ_ID)) {
        initEngineAndJoinChannel();
    }
}

private void initUI() {
    mLocalContainer = findViewById(R.id.local_video_view_container);
    mRemoteContainer = findViewById(R.id.remote_video_view_container);

    mCallBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
    mMuteBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_mute);
    mSwitchCameraBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_switch_camera);

    mLogView = findViewById(R.id.log_recycler_view);

    // Sample logs are optional.
    showSampleLogs();
}

private void showSampleLogs() {
    mLogView.logI("Welcome to Agora 1v1 video call");
    mLogView.logW("You will see custom logs here");
    mLogView.logE("You can also use this to show errors");
}

private boolean checkSelfPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS, requestCode);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQ_ID) {
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                grantResults[1] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                grantResults[2] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            showLongToast("Need permissions " + Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO +
                    "/" + Manifest.permission.CAMERA + "/" + Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Here we continue only if all permissions are granted.
        // The permissions can also be granted in the system settings manually.
        initEngineAndJoinChannel();
    }
}

private void showLongToast(final String msg) {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

private void initEngineAndJoinChannel() {
    // This is our usual steps for joining
    // a channel and starting a call.
    initializeEngine();
    setupVideoConfig();
    setupLocalVideo();
    joinChannel();
}

private void initializeEngine() {
    try {
        mRtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.agora_app_id), mRtcEventHandler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        throw new RuntimeException("NEED TO check rtc sdk init fatal error\n" + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}

private void setupVideoConfig() {
    // In simple use cases, we only need to enable video capturing
    // and rendering once at the initialization step.
    // Note: audio recording and playing is enabled by default.
    mRtcEngine.enableVideo();

    // Please go to this page for detailed explanation
    // https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_rtc_engine.html#af5f4de754e2c1f493096641c5c5c1d8f
    mRtcEngine.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(new VideoEncoderConfiguration(
            VideoEncoderConfiguration.VD_640x360,
            VideoEncoderConfiguration.FRAME_RATE.FRAME_RATE_FPS_15,
            VideoEncoderConfiguration.STANDARD_BITRATE,
            VideoEncoderConfiguration.ORIENTATION_MODE.ORIENTATION_MODE_FIXED_PORTRAIT));
}

private void setupLocalVideo() {
    
    mRtcEngine.setupLocalVideo(new VideoCanvas(mLocalView, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN, 0));
}

private void joinChannel() {
    String token = getString(R.string.agora_access_token);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(token) || TextUtils.equals(token, "#YOUR ACCESS TOKEN#")) {
        token = null; // default, no token
    }
    mRtcEngine.joinChannel(token, "demoChannel1", "Extra Optional Data", 0);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (!mCallEnd) {
        leaveChannel();
    }
    /*
      Destroys the RtcEngine instance and releases all resources used by the Agora SDK.

      This method is useful for apps that occasionally make voice or video calls,
      to free up resources for other operations when not making calls.
     */
    RtcEngine.destroy();
}

private void leaveChannel() {
    mRtcEngine.leaveChannel();
}

public void onLocalAudioMuteClicked(View view) {
    mMuted = !mMuted;
    // Stops/Resumes sending the local audio stream.
    mRtcEngine.muteLocalAudioStream(mMuted);
    int res = mMuted ? R.drawable.btn_mute : R.drawable.btn_unmute;
    mMuteBtn.setImageResource(res);
}

public void onSwitchCameraClicked(View view) {
    // Switches between front and rear cameras.
    mRtcEngine.switchCamera();
}

public void onCallClicked(View view) {
    if (mCallEnd) {
        startCall();
        mCallEnd = false;
        mCallBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_endcall);
    } else {
        endCall();
        mCallEnd = true;
        mCallBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_startcall);
    }

    showButtons(!mCallEnd);
}

private void startCall() {
    setupLocalVideo();
    joinChannel();
}

private void endCall() {
    removeLocalVideo();
    removeRemoteVideo();
    leaveChannel();
}

private void removeLocalVideo() {
    if (mLocalView != null) {
        mLocalContainer.removeView(mLocalView);
    }
    mLocalView = null;
}

private void showButtons(boolean show) {
    int visibility = show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
    mMuteBtn.setVisibility(visibility);
    mSwitchCameraBtn.setVisibility(visibility);
}
```

}

I dont really know what is the issue. Anyone have idea on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Is the onFirstRemoteVideoDecoded get triggered?

Comment: @ShaochengYang No, onFirstRemoteVideoDecoded is not triggered. How do I triger it?

Comment: Try use the onRemoteVideoStateChanged callback. Check if the remote video state is "REMOTE_VIDEO_STATE_STARTING". If so, call setupRemoteVideo(uid) method. You can check the onRemoteVideoStateChanged api here: REMOTE_VIDEO_STATE_STARTING(1)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this

you have to add delay of 10 seconds before running below code

```
 mRtcEngine!!.setClientRole(Constants.CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER)
        mRtcEngine!!.joinChannel(
            stringToken,
            channelName,
            "Extra Optional Data",
            currentUid
        )
```

so the surface view of current user is loaded properly first and then it tries to join the call.

Simply put, dont join channel before surface view and camera is ready.